# javascript regex match file extension but excluding prefix extension

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack-loader

I need to match a file extension for webpack rules using regex. I want to make two separate rules for targeting svg files: `*.svg` and `*.icon.svg`.
These rules *must* be mutually exclusive. It's easy to caputure *.icon.svg scenario by testing for `/\.icon.svg$/`. But what should be the expression to capture all `.svg` extensions, excluding the files that end with `.icon.svg`?

Rule example for the `.icon.svg`

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all `.svg` files EXCEPT `.icon.svg`

```
/(?!.*\.icon\.svg$)^.+\.svg$/
```

To match only the `.icon.svg`:

```
/\.icon\.svg$/
```

---

So, that is going to look something like:

```
{
    // match all .svg files EXCEPT .icon.svg
    test: /(?!.*\.icon\.svg$)^.+\.svg$/,
    loader: 'specific-loader-name'
},
{
    // Match only .icon.svg files
    test: /\.icon\.svg$/,
    loader: 'different-loader'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

this shall do the trick.

```
{
   test:/^(?!.*.icon)\.svg$/i 
   ...
}
```

this regex use a thing called negative lookahead, so basically it will exclude anything that contains .icon before ".svg"